# Different ways to phrase “生活的發現”

Tags: translation

The Korean movie On the Occasion of Remembering the Turning Gate has the Chinese title, 生活的發現, which, obviously, has nothing to do with its English version.

*Life's Discovery*, or *Discovery of Life*, are some translations - does anyone have any cool ideas how to phrase that differently, and in a way more palatable to the English speaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the original title described someone was " At the moment of recalling a turning point " (I am interpreting "turning gate" as " a gate that's the turning point of someone's life"-  meaning someone went through a gate (crossed a line/ made a choice) that changed his or her life from that point on).

Obviously, someone interpreted the title similarly and came up with a Chinese title  "(改變)生命的發現" - "a life (changing) discovery" with the implied meaning " changing" omitted. ( someone went thought a gate and discovered something that changed his or her life)

However, the translator confused 生命( one's life) with "生活" ( a living ) , that why the title was translated as "生活的發現" instead of the somewhat more accurate " 生命的發現"

My translation of the original title would be:
"**回望人生轉捩點**" (**A look back at the turning point of life**)

-instead of 回想 (think back/ remember) I choose "回望"( look back/ revisit) - which is an action verb that paint a more vivid picture to simulate imagination.

-Just put 轉捩點 ( a turning point) after 回想(think back) is too general, so I also included the originally implied meaning of "life" to  clarify it is not just any turning point, but a " life's turning point"